# Solve the equation $\sqrt[3]{15-x^3+3x^2-3x}=2\sqrt{x^2-4x+2}+3-x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, radicals, radical-equations

Solve the equation $\sqrt[3]{15-x^3+3x^2-3x}=2\sqrt{x^2-4x+2}+3-x$.

I have tried to solve for x by Casio and try to make the equation to $u.v=0$ but the solution is not in $\mathbb{Q}$. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: potentially interesting rewrite, but now sure how useful yet $$\sqrt[3]{14 - (x-1)^3} = 2\sqrt{(x-2)^2-2} - (x-3)$$

Comment: I have rewrite this but I'm stuck now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the square root to be defined we need:

$$x^2-4x+2\geq 0$$

Therefore, we have:

$$2\sqrt{x^2-4x+2} = x-3+\sqrt[3]{15-x^3+3x^2-3x}=$$

$$=\frac{(x-3)^3+15-x^3+2x^2-3x}{(x-3)^2-(x-3)\sqrt[3]{15-x^3+3x^2-3x}+\sqrt[3]{(15-x^3+3x^2-3x)^2}}$$

$$=\frac{-6(x^2-4x+2)}{(x-3)^2-(x-3)\sqrt[3]{15-x^3+3x^2-3x}+\sqrt[3]{(15-x^3+3x^2-3x)^2}}\leq 0$$

The numerator is negative $x^2-4x+2 \geq 0 \Rightarrow -6(x^2-4x+2)\leq 0$.  The denominator is of the form $a^2-ab+b^2$ which is always non-negative because:

$$a^2-ab+b^2=\frac{1}{2}[a^2+b^2+(a-b)^2]\geq 0$$

And thus $x^2-4x+2=0$ which means $x=2\pm\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Can you explain more why it's $\le 0$?

Comment: @NguyenThy, Because the numerator is negative. $x^2-4x+2 \geq 0 \Rightarrow -6(x^2-4x+2)\leq 0$

Comment: How about determinator ?

Comment: @NguyenThy, I edited to add more detail.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much.